# Detect when dataview is not changed

Tags: slickgrid, dataview

Currently there are 3 events for the Dataview, namely onRowCountChanged, onRowChanged and onPagingInfoChanged, which are all events when there is a change in the dataview's # of rows. If I use the Dataview's front-end filtering and there is no change in row, I like to do something. How can I detect if user has activated the filtering and there is no change in # rows? Was unable to locate any such event. Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your code there only where

**`grid.sort`**,
 **`grid.scroll`**,
 **`dataView.onRowCountChanged`**, etc are defined....since you are refreshing/rendering the dataView on filter irrespective of whether row count is changed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I eventually did was enable a flag just before the filter starts. After the setfilter is called, I disable the flag after x secs with a setTimeout (in the event that there is no change in dataview). In the onRowCountChanged, disable the flag if there is change. Must admit that it is not a good method but it achieved the objective in my case. :)